Wrong typings for z.enum
Hello everyone i have a code like this:
import { z } from 'zod'

const options = [
    ["a", { label: "A" }],
    ["b", { label: "B" }],
]  as const

export function optionsToEnum<T>(entries: ReadonlyArray<Readonly<[value: T, { label: string }]>>): [T, ...T[]] {
    const [firstValue, ...restValues] = entries.map(([value]) => value)

    return [firstValue, ...restValues]
}

const a = optionsToEnum(options) // typeof a is ["a" | "b", ...("a" | "b")[]] but i expected ["a", "b"]

z.enum(a)

Why typeof a is ["a" | "b", ...("a" | "b")[]] i expected ["a", "b"] and how to fix this?

Here is the corrected version that addresses the incorrectly typed variable a issue as well as callback signature mismatch with map function: Argument type ([value]: readonly [any]) => any is not assignable to parameter type <T>(value: Readonly<[T, {label: string}]>, index: number, array: Readonly<[T, {label: string}]>[]) => any :
import { z } from 'zod';

const options = [
    ["a", { label: "A" }],
    ["b", { label: "B" }],
] as const;

type ValueOf<T> = T extends Readonly<[infer U, any]> ? U : never;

export function optionsToEnum<T extends ReadonlyArray<Readonly<[any, { label: string }]>>>(entries: T): { [K in keyof T]: ValueOf<T[K]> } {
    return entries.map(([value, _]) => value);
}

const a = optionsToEnum(options);
// typeof a = readonly ["a", "b"]

z.enum(a);


The problem was that type T was inferred for the entire array, not for individual types for each tuple element, and therefore was unified as type "a" | "b".

Thanks for the answer, but there is an error here

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFAxhAHYDO8EYMw9DcAvHANoVxBfAEQBDYQBpEcADaiARgFMZALjjCAgsPQBdCQKG9h8ydLlLV6gELa0eijrijOtRjEoUYATzCK4ANVEZAFdFAHlMAB4AFQA+bjhouEUADxhFOmJOACVFUWJ6GS9I3mA6TEUoOABVKVE6Lx14gH4auDU6RQA3So9UyFgsYLpqNno4FjHGaIgAUTpgkBjktIysuFz8wq8NKChRYs2CuiKS+q8pJHNlNSYoMoBzXViXgAoMmHvFBjVogEo1EheABpOBlOAAa0UXggmESOjUgRC4Si0RBTXQiAMgigihgwSgdGSdE+wG+ADoQKIwK9XrwukFQlIAPo6P7ceIM5F-ShoKiuJhOBKTdjTOYLECvEUcHkUAD0crg3l8sKFPFxWxOXhE4ikxmEOioyHJGUWr1EPKAA

Indeed, the result of entries.map(([value, _]) => value) is typed as any[] which may or may not cause typing error depending on tsconfig settings, in my case IDE was not indicating it as an error. It looks like we need to resort to as expressions to convince type checker e.g. adding as any when returning. This is kind of unfortunate but at call sites type inference works correctly.
